# jQuery only use one event ignore the rest

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#TextBoxConfirmNewEmail').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#cut_copy_paste').html("Please re-type email address for verification.").fadeIn(1);
        $('#cut_copy_paste').html("Please re-type email address for verification.").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
    });

</script>
```

I am sure there is a way to simplify this code but my question is this. It is being called once and it works but if I Ctrl+V, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+V multiple times. It is being executed multiple times. I am trying to only grab one event and dump the rest.

Basically I am trying to show the message when the person Cut, Copy or Paste and then slowly let that message fade. If the person presses the Ctrl+V quickly again ignore it until the message is completely faded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var runVer = true;
    $('#TextBoxConfirmNewEmail').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (runVer)
        {
            runVer = false;
            $('#cut_copy_paste').html("Please re-type email address for verification.").fadeIn(1);
            $('#cut_copy_paste').html("Please re-type email address for verification.").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                runVer = true;
            }, 3000);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This one is simple to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine doing something like this:

```
$('#TextBoxConfirmNewEmail').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $ccp = $('#cut_copy_paste');
    if($ccp.data('abort')==true)
        return 0;

    $ccp.data('abort',true).html("Please re-type email address for verification.").fadeIn(1).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).data('abort',false); });
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2UuZ/